# No puedo convertir string a datetime C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde estoy guardando fechas en varchar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un ModelView donde almaceno lo que viene de la base de datos:

**MV**

```
 public class PulseJetModelView
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
        public string NumParte { get; set; }
        public string NombreMaterialUnion { get; set; }
        public string NombreMaterial { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Aprobado { get; set; }
        public string Revision { get; set; }
        public string Diametro { get; set; }
        public string Largo { get; set; }
        public string Top { get; set; }
        public string Bottom { get; set; }
        public string Otras { get; set; }
        public string Dado { get; set; }
        public string UniCajas { get; set; }
        public string OrdenEmitida { get; set; }
        public string ClienteFinal { get; set; }
        public string Comentarios { get; set; }
        public bool? HayApro { get; set; }
        public bool? HayMail { get; set; }
        public bool? HayFotos { get; set; }
        public bool? HayComen { get; set; }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
// GET: Pulse
        public ActionResult Pulse()
        {
            var listadoPulseJet = clienteServicio.DatosPulseJet();
            List<PulseJetModelView> pulseMap = new List<PulseJetModelView>();

            foreach (var item in listadoPulseJet)
            {
                PulseJetModelView _item = new PulseJetModelView();
                _item.Id = item.Id;
                _item.Material = item.Material;
                _item.NumParte = item.NumParte;
                _item.NombreMaterialUnion = item.Material_Nombre;
                _item.NombreMaterial = item.NombreMaterial;
                _item.Aprobado = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Aprobado, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                _item.Revision = item.Revision;
                _item.Diametro = item.Diametro;
                _item.Largo = item.Largo;
                _item.Top = item.Top;
                _item.Bottom = item.Bottom;
                _item.Otras = item.Otras;
                _item.Dado = item.Aros;
                _item.UniCajas = item.UniCajas;
                _item.OrdenEmitida = item.OrdenEmitida;
                _item.ClienteFinal = item.ClienteFinal;
                _item.Comentarios = item.Comentarios;
                _item.HayApro = item.HayApro;
                _item.HayMail = item.HayMail;
                _item.HayFotos = item.HayFotos;
                _item.HayComen = item.HayComen;
                pulseMap.Add(_item);
            }
            return View(pulseMap);
        }
```

Quiero transformar los strings en `datetime` pero resulta que siempre que llega al `id=16` de la tabla (la cual tiene fecha de `14/02/201`4) la aplicacion revienta. No se si sea que el `cultural` esta malo o no pero antes de ese `id` las demas fecha si las toma, como puedo convertir las fechas de string a date correctamente?

El error que me lanza es:

> 'No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.'

**EDIT**

captura de lo que llega o hay en el loop en el momento de fallar (notese que `aprobado`tiene datos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Será por el doble punto y coma `;;` que tienes ahí, sino qué error es el que te lanza.

Comment: @Vlady dedazo, ya lo quite. El error que lanza es `'No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTime válido.'`

Comment: Si pones un punto de depuración en esa línea, estás seguro que `item.Aprobado` tiene valor?, es como si la variable estuviera vacía o `null`

Comment: Quítale el `DateTime?` y pon solo un `DateTime` a ver que pasa

Comment: @Vlady, el pasa del id 12 al 15 correctamente (esos que tienen fechas de `01/01/XXXX`) pero a la hora de cambiar a datetime la del id 16 la cual es `14/02/2014` da el error, toda la columna de `aprobado` esta llena

Comment: @RafaelAcosta da el mismo error

Comment: Prueba con Convert.ToDateTime(_item.Aprobado)

Comment: Puedes adjuntar una captura de pantalla del error? Siento que estamos obviando algo, o copiar todo el texto incluso lo que no parece relevante.

Comment: @Vlady agregado

Comment: Al parecer tienes un espacio extra al final, prueba agregando `trim`: `item.Aprobado.Trim()`

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que te está tomando el 14 como mes (el mes 14 no existe) y el 2 como día. Por eso cuando es 01/01, el mes 1 y el día 1 si existen y no da error.

Comment: @Vlady era un espacio que habia, eso causaba la excepcion, Gracias

Comment: @RafaelAcosta la respuesta que habias posteado era la correcta solo que no habia notado el espacio, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que está interpretando el **14** de la fecha como si fuera el **mes** y no el **día**.

Indica la "cultura" que quieres utilizar directamente creando un nuevo objeto `new CultureInfo("es-ES")`.

```
_item.Aprobado = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Aprobado.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

Comment: Yo creo que es lo mismo, pero ya lo aplique y sigue fallando igual

Comment: Aun así, tiene toda la pinta de que te está tomando el 14 como mes (el mes 14 no existe) y el 2 como día. Por eso cuando es 01/01,  el mes 1 y el día 1 si existen y no da error.

Answer (score 1):

Casi todo esta bien lo que sucede es que no estas agregando un patron que reconozca la hora.

Puedes agregar el patron de la hora

```
Funcionaria con una fecha asi "19/01/2020 0:00:00" 
y las horas van unicamente del 0 al 12
"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss"

Funcionaria con una fecha asi "19/01/2020 00:00:00 PM"
y las horas van unicamente del 0 al 12 especificando AM/PM
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"

Funcionaria con una fecha asi "19/01/2020 00:00 AM" 
y las horas van unicamente del 0 al 12 especificando AM/PM
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"
```

Puedes extraer la fecha

```
var FechaEnString = "01/01/2020 0:00:00";
var FechaCasteada = DateTime.Parse(FechaEnString);
```

Puedes partir en dos la cadena que contiene la fecha a partir del especio y tomar la primera parte con la fecha

```
var FechaEnString = "01/01/2020 0:00:00".split(' ')[0];
var FechaCasteada = DateTime.ParseExact(FechaEnString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```